# I can not use my class

Tags: android, class

I made a simple class to get two integer values and add them together and return the output as an integer. this is my class in plussum.java class:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

public class plusSum
{

// variables

// empty constructor
public plusSum(){}

// constructor
public int sumIt(int a, int b){
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
}
```

This is my mainactivity.java :

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
EditText val1;
EditText val2;
int rslt,finalval1,finalval2;
Button btn;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
                val1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
            val2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
            String fv = val1.getText().toString();
            finalval1 = Integer.parseInt(fv);
            finalval2 = Integer.parseInt(val2.getText().toString());

            int summed = plusSum.sumIt(finalval1,finalval2);
            TextView rslt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rslt);
            rslt.setText(summed);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Error there is no such a reference here for sumIt... 
any helps...? 
I am a noob and just started to learn how to script for Android...

Comment: create a new instance of your class or make your method static.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the method static so you could call it without instantiating the class:

```
public static int sumIt(int a, int b){
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

Or instantiate your class and then call it:

```
plusSum myClass = new plusSum();
int summed = myClass.sumIt(finalval1,finalval2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of your class before you can use it like this:

```
plusSum sp = new plusSum();
int summed = sp.sumIt(finalval1,finalval2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
plusSum plussum=new plusSum();
int summed = plussum.sumIt(finalval1,finalval2);
```

or:

```
int summed = new plusSum().sumIt(finalval1,finalval2);
```